# Interacting with checkboxes in Rshiny for overlapping plots

Tags: r, shiny

I am struggling trying to graph two overlaying plots and add checkboxes fro displaying them in my Rshiny app.  I am using the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs) 


mpgData <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title

  titlePanel("Test"),


  # Sidebar with checkboxes to select plot

  sidebarLayout(



    sidebarPanel(


      helpText("Select type of plot:"),

      checkboxGroupInput("checkPlot", 

                         label = ("Plots"), 

                         choices=c("Baseline","Scenario A"),

                         selected = c("Baseline","Scenario A")

      )

  ),

  mainPanel(
     textOutput("overview"),

      plotOutput("plot")
  )

  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  #get Check group input (type of plot)

  checkedVal <- reactive({

    as.vector(input$checkPlot)


  }) 

  #plot
  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    if(("Baseline" %in% checkedVal()) & ("Scenario A" %in% checkedVal()))

       # first plot
       plot(mpgData$mpg, mpgData$cyl, type='l',col="steelblue",ylim=range(c(mpgData$cyl,mpgData$disp)))

       # second plot
       par(new = TRUE)
       plot(mpgData$mpg, mpgData$disp, type = "l",col="red", ylim=range(c(mpgData$cyl,mpgData$disp)), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")


    if ("Baseline" %in% checkedVal())

   plot(mpgData$mpg, mpgData$cyl, type='l',col = "steelblue")

    if ("Scenario A" %in% checkedVal())


      plot(mpgData$mpg, mpgData$disp, type='l',col = "red")

  })


}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My checkboxes seem to be working out alright when I just want one graph to be displayed, however, there's definitely an issue when I want to display both on the same axes. Most examples I saw were a little too complex for me to understand and break down, so I tired to infer from previous R knowledge, but clearly I'm off.

any help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were trying to add the baseline on the existing graph, you could use the lines function, as below. Although if for your particular data-set, the base line is really negligible compared to the original plot, you need to use a package other than 'base', like 'ggplot'.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs) 


mpgData <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title

  titlePanel("Test"),


  # Sidebar with checkboxes to select plot

  sidebarLayout(



    sidebarPanel(


      helpText("Select type of plot:"),

      checkboxGroupInput("checkPlot", 

                         label = ("Plots"), 

                         choices=c("Baseline","Scenario A"),

                         selected = c("Baseline","Scenario A")

      )

    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("overview"),

      plotOutput("plot")
    )

  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  #get Check group input (type of plot)

  checkedVal <- reactive({
    as.vector(input$checkPlot)
  }) 

  #plot


  # first plot
  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    if(("Baseline" %in% checkedVal()) & ("Scenario A" %in% checkedVal()))
    {   plot(mpgData$mpg, mpgData$cyl, type='l',col="steelblue",ylim=range(c(mpgData$cyl,mpgData$disp)))
      lines(mpgData$mpg, mpgData$disp, type = "l",col="red")
    }
    else if("Baseline" %in% checkedVal())
    {   
      plot(mpgData$mpg, mpgData$cyl, type='l',col = "steelblue")
    }
    else if("Scenario A" %in% checkedVal())
    {
      plot(mpgData$mpg, mpgData$disp, type='l',col = "red")
    }
  })




}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much ! This work perfectly...I will look into ggplot should my needs change.